# how to reset a dynamically/ajax-ly added/created form using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

In my webpage a form is inserted via Ajax. I am using `$("#my-ajax-returned-form")[0].reset();`
 to reset the form but it doesn't work for me. Firebug console shows `TypeError: $("#my-ajax-returned-form")[0] is undefined`. Any clue how to fix it? The actual flow is as following and its plain vanilla AJAX with jquery

- Click on a icon sends an ajax call to server
- The server sends a form which is inserted into webpage using `$('#target-div').html(returnedFormHTML)` which contains my form with id `my-ajax-returned-form`
- User fills up form and clicks save, data is posted to server using `$.post()`
- On success I fire another method which is trying to reset `my-ajax-returned-form` using `$("#my-ajax-returned-form")[0].reset();`

Now, it is obvious that form has to be some `live` in some sense but I am unable to figure it out :(

Here is the main webpage - http://pastebin.com/rtkr8RUC
Here is the #my-ajax-returned-form form - http://pastebin.com/jtjakgUt
I can not post the complete code on jsfiddle easily, bear with me for that

**Update**
I found the issue, there is a reset button in the form named reset, so obviously form.reset is not a function.
But the `textarea` is still not reset!
Fixed the textarea issue as well

Comment: Probably you don't have an element with that ID at the time it is called. Could you post the appropriate code please?

Comment: I can not post the code as such but I can post the pseudo code

Comment: Perhaps you might want to post a non-working narrowed-down fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: `live` is for binding objects to events and has nothing to do with finding then in the DOM.

Comment: You really need to post some code. You say you can not post code. Why not?

Comment: @Lee many reasons, one being NDA, another being bit lazy, but give me time & I will post modified code to jsfiddle

Comment: I seriously doubt that any part of the NDA could be used to cover generic HTML/JS. NDAs are there to protect the business logic, not the parts anybody can get via their browser.

Comment: @Zanfa, will the argument of being lazy work?

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` clearly indicates that there's a problem finding the form. Are you sure the selector is correct, are you looking for it inside the correct iframe etc. Try logging the `$("#my-ajax-returned-form")` to see if it finds anything.

Comment: been there done that, when I write JS my firebug console area is normally larger my browser window :D

Comment: @Kumar Well yeah, but what did it log? Did it find the element or not?

Comment: here it is `[form#[object HTMLInputElement].my-ajax-returned-form save]`, it logs the form

Comment: Is that an HTMLInputElement? Those don't have reset() function. Only forms do.

Comment: @Kumar in the code you posted `$('#guest-reviews-form').reset();` Tries to do the reset on a jQuery object, didn't see anything that resembles your originally posted code more than that line.

Comment: my bad, updated the post, copied code from already opened tab, post updated

Answer (score 0):

You could try $('#my-ajax-returned-form').eq(0).reset(), but since the selector is an id and so should be unique, this doesn't seem to make much sense.

On the other hand, is the reset() - function even defined?

Comment: Yes, `HTMLFormElement.prototype.reset` is a function.